# Add data to dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary

Here is my dictionary:

```
inventory = {
    'gold' : 500,
    'pouch' : ['flint', 'twine', 'gemstone'], # Assigned a new list to 'pouch' key
    'backpack' : ['xylophone','dagger', 'bedroll','bread loaf']
}
```

I need to add 50 to the index of `gold`. 
What should I do? I tried:

```
inventory['gold'].append(50)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gold` is not a list. It is an *integer*, so you use *addition*:

```
inventory['gold'] += 50
```

This uses augmented assignment, which for integers is equivalent to:

```
inventory['gold'] = inventory['gold'] + 50
```

If you need `gold` to be a list as well, and want to end up with `[500, 50]` as the value, you'll have to *replace* the current value with a list:

```
inventory['gold'] = [inventory['gold'], 50]
```

If you need to add multiple values over time, and don't know if `gold` is a list or a simple integer, and *cannot change the original dictionary* to *always* use a list, you could use exception handling:

```
try:
    inventory['gold'].append(50)
except AttributeError:
    # not a list yet
    inventory['gold'] = [inventory['gold'], 50]
```

It would be far easier to maintain your project if you *started* with `gold` always being a list object, however.

Comment: Downvoted as the question was edited to match this answer, with my answer embedded into this one in case that op didn't mean addition. I'm completely pro a complete answer. Which is what you've now got, but the edit to the question made it look shady. - Otherwise I wouldn't mind

Comment: @Scironic: I always expand answers to cover all bases I think of. I did not need to consult your answer to do so. You are free to update *your* answer too. Personally, I use voting to reflect the helpfulness of answers, not for perceived plagiarism, that is what flagging is for.

Comment: I understand that, I do the same. My point was that you edited the question to suit your answer more favourably (with or without intention to do so).

Comment: @Scironic: the goal here is to provide good answers to questions. I'm sorry that you feel something shady is going on, but I can assure you I make all my edits on my own terms.

Comment: @Scironic: wait, you said *edited the **question*** to match my answer?! I thought you were talking about my edits to my own answer here. I always clean up questions, make *editorial* edits (spelling, grammar, formatting, clarity). You are encouraged to do so (there is a series of badges for that). I certainly did **not** edit it to match my answer. Where do you see that?

Comment: the edit went from 'need to 50 to the index of gold` to `need to add 50 to the index of gold`, making the q match your answer. As I said, I'm sure it was non-intentional, but it didn't look good.

Comment: @Scironic: the sentence made no grammatical sense without a verb. Adding something to the 50 can mean mathematical addition or appending to a list; I fail to see how that looks dodgy.

Comment: Again, I agree that the sentence makes no sense without a verb. But you presumed the verb to go there was the one that fitted your answer, immediately putting my answer out of context and strengthening the context of yours. Whilst the sentence needed a verb, I think it would have been best to confirm from OP which verb was needed.

Comment: @Scironic: and what verb would have suited your answer better? `append`? I picked `add` precisely because it can fit both interpretations equally well. And you are free to ask the OP for clarification there, but can I ask you to keep taking the [suite guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice) in mind and *assume good intentions*?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you mean you want to append 50 to gold. Make gold a list:

```
inventory = {
    'gold' : [500],
    'pouch' : ['flint', 'twine', 'gemstone'], # Assigned a new list to 'pouch' key
    'backpack' : ['xylophone','dagger', 'bedroll','bread loaf']
}

inventory['gold'].append(50)
```

If you meant add, use Martijn's solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add 60 to the value of the key "Platinum"

```
inventory ["Platinum"] += 60
```

If you want to keep the value of 500 but also have a value of 60 you need something to contain them both such as a list.

You could initialize your "Platinum" value with a list and then append 500 and then 60 to it.

```
inventory ["Platinum"] = list ()
inventory ["Platinum"].append (500)
inventory ["Platinum"].append (60)
```

Or you could use the defaultdict to make it slightly simpler.

```
from collections import defaultdict


inventory = defaultdict (list)  # every missing value is now a list.

inventory ["Platinum"].append (500) # add 500 to the list.
inventory ["Platinum"].append (60) # add 60 to the list.
inventory ["pouch"] = ['Flint', 'twine', 'gemstone'] # create a new key with a new value.
inventory['animals'].extend(['Elephant', 'dog','lion']) # extend list to include.
inventory['pouch'].remove('Flint')
```