# how to add items to the list that is in the dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

```
inventory = {
    'gold' : 500,
    'pouch' : ['flint', 'twine', 'gemstone'], # Assigned a new list to 'pouch' key
    'backpack' : ['xylophone','dagger', 'bedroll','bread loaf'],
    'pocket': ['seashell','strange berry','lint'] 
}
```

how to Add 50 to the number stored under the 'gold' key

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27942793/add-data-to-dictionary-in-python/27942821#27942821 today is the day of gold ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elementary, Watson:

```
 inventory['gold'] += 50
```